What is the correct preposition for imagine?
I would like to know if the following sentence is correct.
It might be different from what you imagine from shaved ice.

Context: I work at a restaurant that serves unusual shaved ice and I would like to explain to customers when ordering it that they might be getting something different, in this case, unusual shaved ice so as not to surprise them.
Should I use maybe of instead of from like the following?
It might be different from what you imagine of shaved ice.

What is the correct preposition for imagine?

It might be different from the shaved ice you are used to.

what you imagine shaved ice to be? what you imagine when you think of shaved ice? Are you imagining the ice, or are you anticipating people thinking of ice and then thinking of something different or more specific?

If a customer orders "shaved ice", it's very likely they've had something by that name before. Hence contextually it's a bit insulting to imply they only imagine what it's like - if they've had it before, they know what it's like (or at least, what it should be like). You admit yourself that the shaved ice your establishment serves is "unusual", so you should explain why it's different and avoid implying criticism of the customer for not knowing about your "non-standard" version in advance.

You might be making too much of Our shaved ice is unusual if you have to prepare your public at all. A long explanation could sound pretentious.

imagine about something.


"Imagine" doesn't usually take a preposition at all with its objects. "I imagine purple penguins," not "I imagine of purple penguins." The most idiomatic version of your proposed sentence would be: "It might be different from what you imagine shaved ice to be."
But is "imagine" really the word you want here? It might be more at home with something you've never experienced (like purple penguins). Assuming that the customer has actually had shaved ice before, the real point here is that your product is outside of their expectation. And "expect" does use prepositions:


It might be different from what you expect of shaved ice.

I feel like you could reasonably use either "of" or "from" here, but I chose "of" since it has a bit more implication of "what you expect to shaved ice to be," while "from" might be more suited for a situation in which something comes from something, like "what you expect from a shaved ice truck."
